# WPF RadDatePicker Enter Date Order

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, datetime-format, telerik-raddatepicker

I have form with more than one RadDatePicker, Every thing work fine but when I want to enter date I want the end user enter date in format dd/mm/yyyy
BUT the tool accept only date in format mm/dd/yyyy order!!

**Example**: 13/12/2016 
If the user enter 13 then press spacebar then type 12 then press spacebar 2016 then press enter It gives Error

[image]

How can I change the format for entering date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just going by what is in your question, if you want/need a particular format, and the selected tool does not support that format, pick a different tool. Or write your own tool.

Comment: @Kevin I'm asking if I can do what I want to do using this tool !

Answer (score 1):

Try set `ShortDatePattern` in `DateTimeFormatInfo`:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");  
DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();  
dateInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";  
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat = dateInfo;  
radDatePicker1.Culture = cultureInfo;
```

You should also implement custom parsing: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddatetimepicker/how-to/implement-custom-parsing

Example:

```
private void radDateTimePicker_ParseDateTimeValue(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.ParseDateTimeEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime date;
    string input = args.TextToParse.ToLower();
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        args.Result = date;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsParsingSuccessful = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used the Culture but it workd for display date after enter the date, What I want to applied this format when the user enter the date

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif check my answer again :)

Comment: I follow your link, Can you helped my how to use the ParseDateTimeValue to accomplish what want :)

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif check my answer. I have added example.

Comment: I test the example, But it also gives an error entring date

Comment: I thank you so much for your help, I solved the issue by changing the culture from "en-US" to "ar-LY".

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the issue by changing the culture from "en-US" to "ar-LY"

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker Culture="ar-LY"/>
```

Also, You can check [.NET Framework Cultures with Date and Time String Formats](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx)

Hope this help.